# Prove $\forall a,b \in \mathbb{Z}$, $a^2 -4b - 3 \ne 0$ using proof by contradiction

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Prove $\forall a,b \in \mathbb{Z}$, $a^2 -4b - 3 \ne 0$

I want to do a proof by Contradiction. I know that this can be figured out using Rational root theorem by subbing in (1, -1, 3, -3), but I am looking for another method in tackling the problem.

So Assume $a^2 -4b - 3 = 0$

$a^2 - 4b = 3$

I don't know what to do next, there is nothing I can figure out regarding the $a^2$ and $4b$.

A similar question is $\forall a,b \in \mathbb{Z}$, $a^2 -4b - 2 \ne 0$

But in this case it is much simpler with doing a proof by contradiction.

$a^2 = 2(2b + 1)$
Then from this I can figure out that $a$ is even and work from there.

But I am stuck how to prove that this statement is false:

$a^2 -4b - 3 = 0$

Comment: This "then" is supefluous (to say the least).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$a^2=4b+3 \implies a^2\equiv 3\mod 4$    Contradiction!

Answer (score 1):

Consider the remainder of $a^2 \pmod 4$. Which values can it take?

Comment: As 1k5 says, consider it and then try with even $a$ or $a=2n$ and odd $a$ or $a=2n+1$. In both cases the reminder is not equal to 3.

Answer (score 0):

Let $a=2n$ be even.

$$4n^2-4b=3\implies n^2-b=\frac34\text{ !}$$

Let $a=2n+1$ be odd.

$$4n^2+4n+1-4b=3\implies n^2+n-b=\frac12\text{ !}$$