# How do I figure out which strategy to use when proving a theorem?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-explanation

> Prove $\forall a,b \in \mathbb{Z}, a^2−4b−3 \ne 0$

So, I've been given the above statement to prove. Here, I don't expect the answer because it's already there [here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1052060/440233)

I've solved many questions on methods of proof but still I find questions where I cannot think of a way to prove it. At times, I can think of something but however, for some reason it doesn't work.

For example, in the question above, what first came to my mind is something to do with roots. But then, it's not a quadratic equation. Then, my next approach was to use the method of contraposition where I assume that a^2−4b−3≠0 is true and try to prove that 'a' and 'b' are are not integers. That didn't work out either.

When I searched for it on the internet I found [this.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1052060/440233) Here, they have shown that 'a' is an even number and have proceeded from there onwards.

I don't understand how and why did they even think of such a proof where I didn't even have the slightest idea to use this strategy.

How do I figure out the right and best strategy? How do you figure it out?

Comment: if it helps I was never able to solve this by myself. But after the third time I saw it solved I can now solve problems similar to it because I am familiarized with it. Also, the way that problem is written seems a bit unnatural, usually it would be phrased as follows: Show $a^2$ is never of the form $4b+3$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would look at it and see that it’s equivalent to the equation $a^2=4b+3$. That’s basically just a fancy way of saying that $a^2$ has a remainder of $3$ when divided by $4$, so I would ask myself whether that is actually possible. It’s pretty obviously impossible if $a$ is even, so what happens when $a$ is odd? In that case $a=2n+1$ for some integer $n$, and

$$a^2=(2n+1)^2=4n^2+4n+1=4(n^2+n)+1\,,$$

which has a remainder of $1$, not $3$, when divided by $4$.

Of course all of this is aided by experience, but that is also pretty much how I’d have approached it 60 years ago.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you please explain why you say that it is impossible for a^2 to have a remainder of 3 when divided by 4?

Comment: Isn't the remainder greater than or equal to 0 and less than the quotient?

Comment: @S.Tiss: Most of my answer **is** an explanation of that. Can you pin down what part of that you don’t understand? \\ No, the remainder is greater than or equal to $0$ and less than the **divisor**, in this case $4$.

Comment: Yes, this part is fine : "a^2=4b+3". What I don't understand is the reason you are saying "It’s pretty obviously impossible if a is even"

Comment: @S.Tiss: If $a$ is even, so is $a^2$, but $4b+3$ is clearly odd, so it can’t be equal to $a^2$.

Comment: thank you very much. It really helped.

Comment: @S.Tiss: You’re very welcome; I’m glad that it helped.